# undefined reference to `__ctype_b_loc' etc

Tags: gcc, curl, arm, libcurl

I am compiling curl for an embedded device, and get:

main.c:(.text+0x375c): undefined reference to `__strdup'
main.c:(.text+0x3818): undefined reference to`__ctype_b_loc'
__fxstat64 etc

I have tried varied -lc etc.

From some research it seems there can be a mixup with older versions (__ctype_b).
I also suspect a mixup between C and C++.

(These are from makefiles generated with builtools (configure), and quite a lot of sourcefiles.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a broken cross-compiler setup. Those symbols (functions) are typically provided by your libc.

curl is frequently successfully built cross-compiled by users, which would be a hint that this problem may be in your environment and not in curl. Assuming you use a decently modern curl version for this.

If things keep being broken, consider using the curl-library mailing list to get help from the libcurl hackers directly.